# SQL starting and ending time parameters not recognized

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

i want not to have to edit starting and ending parameters into code but rather to get prompted for starting and ending after I run the code, but the parameters are not working

```
PARAMETERS [@Starting] Datetime, [@Ending] Datetime;
SELECT tblAttendance.CustomerID, tblAttendance.VisitDate, tblAttendance.ACode, tblAttendance.Days, tblAttendance.ITDays
FROM tblAttendance
WHERE (((tblAttendance.VisitDate) Between [@Starting] And [@Ending]) 
AND ((tblAttendance.VisitTypeCode) Not Like "O") 
AND ((Exists (
       SELECT 1
       FROM tblRecords
       WHERE tblRecords.CustomerID = tblAttendance.CustomerID
       AND tblRecords.DispenseDate = tblAttendance.VisitDate
       AND tblRecords.IsTransit = 0))=False) 
AND ((tblAttendance.Days) Not Like 0));
```

initializing the parameters at the beginning of the code

Comment: "Not working" means what - error message wrong result, nothing happens? Show example data as formatted text table and inputs. I never use dynamic popup input parameters in query because cannot validate user input. Reference controls on form for input.